# Trying to Automate Sikuli but the runIDE is nowhere to be found

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide, sikuli-x

I am testing Sikuli as a desktop automation.
I "installed" Sikuli which is just me running the executable everytime to launch the program.
I am able to write up the flow of the desktop and have it run through the User Interface.
I was looking to see how to run the tests without the user interface and everything I am looking at shows to use the runIDE which is a CMD program. I do not have a runIDE program anywhere in Windows Explorer that I can find.
Is there another install somewhere?

I scoured the internet to find the program and was not able to find it.
I searched far and wide for it on my computer and was unable to find it.
I'm expecting the runIDE to be a program I open and say run file123 in this directory and run file124 in this directory etc.

Answer (score 0):

In actual versions of SikuliX the mentioned command is no longer available.

[See how to run scripts from command line](https://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/010-command-line.html)

Be aware: each run has a startup delay of some seconds.
If this is a problem, you might avoid this delay, by triggering your script runs using hotkeys.

In doubt look into the docs and the net for solutions.

This is RaiMan from SikuliX